# Install-Package : Unable to find package 'FeatureToggle.Core'

Tags: visual-studio-2012, console, toggle, nuget-package, package-managers

When trying to install FeatureToggle from Package Manager Console,
below  eror is coming up.

This happening in VS 2012.

***PM> Install-Package FeatureToggle.Core
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'FeatureToggle.Core'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package FeatureToggle.Core
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package],      InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand***

Answer (score 0):

I was perfectly able to

```
Install-Package FeatureToggle
```

Make sure you have Chosen "All" from the Package Source Dropdown in the console.